# How many Tasogare Otome x Amnesia manga chapters covered by anime?

Tags: dusk-maiden-of-amnesia

I don't want to read the full manga, but I've seen that the manga ended after the anime did. So, I think that the anime won't give the full story.

How many chapters were covered by the anime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information written in [Mangaupdates page of Tasogare Otome x Amnesia](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=41618), the anime started at chapter 1 (with different settings) and ended at at **chapter 23**.

Comment: To add, this would equate to approximately half the manga as Chapter 23 is the last Chapter of Volume 5, there are 10 Volumes of the manga with the last chapter being 45 (not accounting for Omake, Extra or Epilogue chapters)